# Understanding positive and negative rectifiers

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, rectifier, parallel, series

[image]

How is the first circuit a negative rectifier? My thought is the current flows forward so the diode turned into a short and Vout is postive, and if current is reversed then the diode blocks the flow.
For the second circuit, positive voltage is blocked as it does not flow through the diode in the correct direction, and the negative voltage passes through.
There is a hole in my understanding that I am trying to fill.

Comment: Please provide a source for the image

Comment: Tell me what the voltage drop across a diode is.

Comment: Both circuits have their applications so, neither one nor the other can be described as "better".

Comment: I have asked a more general [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/705560/61398) about these diode rectifier configurations that may be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

The question is correct, both are negative rectifiers. I won't address why one is better than the other, because I believe that's the real purpose of this question. Your issue lies with why they both work.

Whatever intuition you are using is obviously letting you down, because it's clearly giving you incorrect results. Allow me to show you how you treat these designs properly, so that you may rebuild a new intuition.

There are three principles that are at work here. The first is Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL). It tells you that the total current entering a node must equal the total current leaving it. In these simple loops, with no paths for current to enter or leave the loop, that can be paraphrased to say that the current is equal at all times, and at all points, around the loop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9kjcZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Current can be negative, indicating that it's flowing the other way. The first thing to do is establish what current will flow, and in which direction, when source \$V_{IN}\$ is positive and when it is negative.

That's pretty obvious. In the left design, current flows, and is positive, \$I > 0\$, when \$V_{IN}>0\$, and no current flows, \$I=0\$ (due to the diode) when \$V_{IN}\le 0\$.

On the right, current flows, and is negative, \$I < 0\$, when \$V_{IN} < 0\$, and no current flows, \$I=0\$ (again due to the diode) when \$V_{IN}\ge 0\$.

---

The second principle is Ohm's law. When current flows through R1, a voltage appears across it, by Ohm's law: \$V=IR\$. Therefore we can immediately expand upon the two scenarios above to determine the conditions under which  R1 will have a zero or non-zero voltage across it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnGUyh.png)</sup>

Notice that (conventional) current always enters a resistor at the terminal with the higher potential (marked "+"), and leave from the lower potential terminal. It is essential to be consistent with your voltage polarity annotations and current arrow directions, in this respect.

For both circuits:

$$ V_R = I R_1 $$

For the left circuit, these are the voltages across R1:

- When \$V_{IN} \le 0\$, no current \$I\$ is flowing, and \$V_R=0\$
- When \$V_{IN} > 0\$, then \$I>0\$ and \$V_R > 0\$

In other words, R1 only develops a non-zero voltage when \$V_{IN}>0\$, and that voltage will be positive.

For the right circuit:

- When \$V_{IN} \ge 0\$, no current \$I\$ is flowing, and \$V_R=0\$
- When \$V_{IN} < 0\$, then \$I<0\$ and \$V_R < 0\$

In other words, R1 only develops a non-zero voltage when \$V_{IN} < 0\$, and that voltage will be negative.

We can also make some statements about the voltage across the diode (which I assume is ideal) in each case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZdruu.png)</sup>

When a diode is passing current, it has no impedance, and the voltage across it will be zero.

- On the left, diode voltage \$V_D = 0\$ when \$I>0\$
- On the right, \$V_D=0\$ when \$I<0\$

---

The last piece of the puzzle is Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL). This is about a journey around a loop. If you start at some place in the loop, having some potential, and you travel around a complete loop adding all rises in potential as you cross each component, or subtracting any falls in potential, when you get back to where you started, you must end up at the same potential as when you started, for a total of *zero* change in potential. It's like walking around town, from place to place. You can go up and down stairs or hills, but when you finally get back to your starting point, you must necessarily have the same altitude that you started with.

For the left circuit, starting at the bottom left and going clockwise (you could start at any point, and go in either direction, and you'll get the same result):

$$ +V_{IN} - V_R - V_D = 0 $$

This is saying that we first encounter a rise in potential as we cross \$V_{IN}\$, so we add that. Then we cross R1, incurring a fall of \$V_R\$ in potential, to be subtracted, and lastly crossing D1 we have another fall \$V_D\$. Back where we started, the total of all changes must be zero.

Another way of writing this is:

$$ V_{IN} = V_R + V_D $$

This can be interpreted to mean that the sum of voltages across the diode and resistor must be equal to the voltage of the source Vin.

On the right, starting bottom left, going clockwise:

$$ +V_{IN} -V_D - V_R = 0 $$

or

$$ V_{IN} = V_R + V_D $$

That's the same result as the left circuit, and we can say the same thing. In both cases, the sum of voltages across R1 and D1 is always equal to the source voltage. We can infer, in both cases:

When \$V_R = 0V\$, then \$V_D = V_{IN}\$.

When \$V_D = 0V\$, then \$V_R = V_{IN}\$.

---

That was a very formal analysis of the states in each case, but now we are ready to put it all together and get some intuition, so that you can conceivably arrive at the correct conclusion without all the horrible algebra.

Start with some tables to summarise the voltages. On the left:

| \$V_{IN}\$ | \$V_R\$ | \$V_D\$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \$\le 0V\$ | \$0V\$ | \$V_{IN}\$ |
| \$>0V\$ | \$V_{IN}\$ | \$0V\$ |

On the right:

| \$V_{IN}\$ | \$V_R\$ | \$V_D\$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \$ < 0V\$ | \$V_{IN}\$ | \$0V\$ |
| \$\ge 0V\$ | \$0V\$ | \$V_{IN}\$ |

Consider *where* you derive the output in each case: it's across D1 on the left, and across R1 on the right. You can consult the tables above to determine the output voltage for all states.

For example, for the left circuit, where output is across D1:

\$ V_{OUT}=V_D=V_{IN}\$ when \$V_{IN}<0\$

For the right circuit, where the output is across R1:

\$ V_{OUT}=V_R=V_{IN}\$ when \$V_{IN}<0\$

Those are identical responses. Both circuits are outputting \$V_{IN}\$ when \$V_{IN} < 0\$, and \$0V\$ otherwise. Both are negative rectifiers.

The intuition you were missing is this: When no current flows, the voltage across R1 *must* be zero, and the voltage across D1 *must* be the entire input source voltage. When current is flowing, the situation is reversed, with R1 developing the entire source voltage and D1 having 0V.

Also, I don't really like your statement that "voltage is blocked". Voltage isn't blocked, only current can be blocked. Voltages across things will change as a result of *current* being blocked or unblocked. Pressures at various points in a water system can change as a result of blockage to water *flow*, but it's wrong to say that the "pressure gets blocked".

While the derivation of these truths was not necessarily trivial, it illustrates why a good understanding of KVL, KCL and Ohm's law, and how they are applied, often results in a rather simple interpretation and conclusion in the end.

Now what remains is for you to find out which of the two circuits performs better than the other, keeping in mind that \$V_{OUT}\$ will have some load attached across it. Hint: Our KCL assumption that current is the same everywhere in the loop, is no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

There are two half-cycles to consider. Just two. Let's say the first half-cycle (#A) is the positive one. Then the second half-cycle (#B) is the negative one.

And given that you write `the diode turned into a short`, I'm going to assume these are `ideal diodes`.

#### left-side circuit

> How is the first circuit a negative rectifier? my thought is the
> current flows forward so the diode turned into a short and v_out is
> pos[i]tive.

Don't just think of one half-cycle. Think of both #A and #B.

Above, you are just thinking about #A. Here, the diode is forward-biased and **on**, and the voltage drop across it is zero (or whatever you are told it is, if not `ideal`.) So during #A, what is the unloaded (\$V_{_\text{OUT}}\$ is left as shown with nothing else attached there) output voltage?

In #B, the diode is reverse-biased and **off**. So during #B, what is the unloaded output voltage, then? And is there any series impedance that may hinder its use by a possible attached load?

#### right-side circuit

> For the second circuit, positive voltage is blocked as it doesnt flow
> through the diode in the correct direction and the negative voltage
> passes through. there is a hole in my understanding that I am trying
> to fill.

In #A, the diode is reverse-biased and **off**. So there's no current in \$R_1\$ and therefore no voltage drop across it. So during #A, what is the unloaded output voltage?

In #B, the diode is forward-biased and **on**, and the voltage drop across it is zero (or whatever you are told it is, if not `ideal`.) So during #B, what is the unloaded output voltage, then? And is there any series impedance that may hinder its use by a possible attached load?

#### summary

Think about the left and right circuits and the questions I asked and see if any thoughts pop to mind about which of the two might make for a better (lower output impedance) negative supply source?